# How to handle different environments in App Store distribution

Tags: flutter, app-store

I have my flutter app in testflight. I tested it, but now I want to move to production (App Store). The problem is that I don't know how to change the environment variables in my app (in test flight is using API test IP and I need to change it to production IP)

[image]

Comment: There is no way to have multiple environments via testflight, unless you control it in the backend, the best way to do this is to have multiple applications for example `com.example.developer (no production just testflight and backend developer)` and for approval `com.example.production, for sending in testflight and later production.`